# Replacing `goto` with a different programming construct

Tags: c, repeat, defensive-programming

I m trying to do this little programm with defensive programming but its more than difficult for me to handle this avoiding the Loop-Goto as i know that as BAD programming. I had try with while and do...while loop but in one case i dont have problem. Problem begins when i m going to make another do...while for the second case ("Not insert space or click enter button"). I tried and nested do...while but here the results was more complicated.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int length;
    char giventext [25];        
    Loop:

    printf("String must have 25 chars lenght:\n");
    gets(giventext);

    length = strlen(giventext);

    if (length > 25) {
        printf("\nString has over %d chars.\nMust give a shorter string\n", length);
        goto Loop;
    }
    /* Here i trying to not give space or nothing*/
    if (length < 1) {
        printf("You dont give anything as a string.\n");
        goto Loop;
    } else {
        printf("Your string has %d\n",length);
        printf("Letter in lower case are: \n");

        for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if (islower(giventext[i])) {                            
                printf("%c",giventext[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can use functions, you always can. What you SHOULD NEVER USE is `gets()`. It's not even present in modern c standard, because that's a very dangerous function.

Comment: Returning to the top of the innermost enclosing loop is what the `continue` statement does.  Alternatively, in your case you could easily make the main part of the loop body (a *real* loop) be conditional on the validation checks passing.  That way you don't need a jump statement of any kind, neither `goto` nor `continue`.

Comment: What do you mean by defensive programming? what are you defending, and from whom?

Comment: @machine_1 Is your question sarcasm?

Comment: @iharob No. But after posting my comment, I realized that defensive programming has a tag, so I clicked it and read the excerpt.

Comment: The first thing you should do is to burn your current source of learning C with fire, then replace it with something that isn't horribly ancient.

Comment: @machine_1 [Defensive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming) is a well-known industry term for writing code that covers error situations that cannot happen in theory, but might happen in practice. As in, you are defending the integrity of your program from unexpected problems like data corruption, EMI, runaway code and bugs in general.

Comment: @Lundin I agree cos something goes wrong for sure but I m learning ANSI c so i must start from this i suppose

Comment: @Lundin The situation that a programm loops everytime untill the input is the right thing that you want from input is not defensive programming? How we call it?

Comment: @Karajohann Defensive programming in this context would mean expect any input. For example, if you ask the user for a number, assume that they might as well type a letter, press enter, or spam your program with a flood of input. The method in the answer by Iharob Al Asimi is a good example of how to write such code in a rugged way. For a beginner, that's way overkill, but for a production-quality program, it is sound practice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that your code is not defensive at all. You have no way to avoid a buffer overflow because,

1. you check for the length of the string after it has been input to your program so after the buffer overflow has already occurred and
2. you used `gets()` which doesn't check input length and thus is very prone to buffer overflow.

Use `fgets()` instead and just discard extra characters.

I think you need to understand that `strlen()` doesn't count the number of characters of input but instead the number of characters in a string.

If you want to ensure that there are less than `N` characters inserted then

```
int
readinput(char *const buffer, int maxlen)
{
    int count;
    int next;

    fputc('>', stdout);
    fputc(' ', stdout);

    count = 0;
    while ((next = fgetc(stdin)) && (next != EOF) && (next != '\n')) {
        // We need space for the terminating '\0';
        if (count == maxlen - 1) {
            // Discard extra characters before returning
            // read until EOF or '\n' is found
            while ((next = fgetc(stdin)) && (next != EOF) && (next != '\n'))
                ;
            return -1;
        }
        buffer[count++] = next;
    }
    buffer[count] = '\0';
    return count;
}

int
main(void)
{
    char string[8];
    int result;

    while ((result = readinput(string, (int) sizeof(string))) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "you cannot input more than `%d' characters\n", 
                            (int) sizeof(string) - 1);
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "accepted `%s' (%d)\n", string, result);
}
```

Note that by using a function, the flow control of this program is clear and simple. That's precisely why `goto` is discouraged, not because it's an evil thing but instead because it can be misused like you did.

Comment: This is a good answer but please note that `ssize_t` is not standard C (but part of POSIX iirc). Personally I would prefer to use something like `bool 
readinput (size_t maxlen, char buffer[maxlen], size_t* chars_read)`, where `chars_read` is optional and can be set to NULL.

Comment: @Lundin I didn't know that! I use it because it could be useful to know the length of the read string after the function returns.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi with buffer overflow means that i have adjust with `char giventext [25];` a string with 25 char but user will put more than this number if understand correct so the array buffer is overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Try using functions that label logical steps that your program needs to execute:

`char * user_input()` - returns an input from the user as a pointer to a char (using something other than `get()`! For example, look at `scanf`)

`bool validate_input(char * str_input)` - takes the user input from the above function and performs checks, such as validate the length is between 1 and 25 characters.

`str_to_lower(char * str_input)` - if `validate_input()` returns true you can then call this function and pass it the user input. The body of this function can then print the user input back to console in lower case. You could use the standard library function `tolower()` here to lower case each character.

The body of your main function will then be much simpler and perform a logical series of steps that tackle your problem. This is the essence of defensive programming - modularising your problem into separate steps that are self contained and easily testable.

A possible structure for the main function could be:

```
char * user_input();
bool validate_input(char *);
void str_to_lower(char *);

int main()
{
    char * str_input = user_input();

    //continue to get input from the user until it satisfies the requirements of 'validate_input()'
    while(!validate_input(str_input)) { 
        str_input = user_input();
    }

    //user input now satisfied 'validate_input' so lower case and print it
    str_to_lower(str_input);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but please keep in mind that the standard lib has a function `tolower` which works on char, not string. So I would propose to name the function `str_tolower` or similar, so these functions aren't mixed up by accident.